# What's the relationship between Ensign Janeway and Capt. Janeway?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, names

In the Star Trek: TNG Episode ["Man of the People"](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/229.htm), we have these lines:

> TROI: Computer today's appointment calendar.
>
> COMPUTER: Oh nine hundred hours, counselling session with ***Ensign Janeway***. Ten hundred hours, counselling session with
>
> TROI: Cancel them. [...]

I assume there is no in-universe relationship between this Ensign and Capt. Janeway.   (If so, what?)

Assuming not, what is the significance of this name?  Does the name 'Janeway' have some special meaning for some member of the writing or production staff?

Comment: It's very likely the two are one in the same. TNG ends on year 2370, Voyager starts it's mission the next year (2371). So it's very possible Janeway is still an Ensign during the events of this episode.

Comment: @onewho - That would be one hell of a promotion. Alas, it conflicts with what we know about ***Captain*** Janeway's career.

Comment: @onewho While the screen writers, should they ever take on Katherine Janeway's story again, might be free to make that interpretation, it would definitely run afoul of extended cannon. The novels register Picard's disappointment at *Commander* Janeway being unavailable to be his first officer aboard The Enterprise-D due to her having accepted her own command.

Comment: Seems rather less likely to me that she'd go from a junior ensign in 2369 to a captain in 2371.

Comment: Welp... I stand corrected then. Disregard my previous comment.

Comment: @onewho, promotions aside, you can bet that if Capt. Janeway had ever served on the Enterprise, it would have been mentioned in Voyager at some point.   Forget extended canon.

Comment: @TZHX:   Well, Kirk did it....

Comment: @ThePopMachine No, Abrahms-Kirk did it, and even then it required the whim of Captain Pike leading to him saving the world. Soft serve is not ice cream.

Comment: No one has addressed the main part of the question: Does the name 'Janeway' have some special meaning for some member of the writing or production staff?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**TL;DR: As of yet, there is no known relationship between the two women (beyond the shared surname), although it's possible both owe their name to Jeri Taylor.**

[**Ensign Janeway**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Janeway_(Ensign)) (first name unknown) was a Sciences officer serving aboard the [NCC-1701-D](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-D)) in the year 2369. We do not know anything else about her, save her appearance and the fact that her duties involved running a diagnostic on the sensor panels. This fact may indicate that she was in [Astrometrics](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Astrometrics), although that is speculation.

In that same year, [**Kathryn Janeway**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kathryn_Janeway) (of [USS Voyager](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Voyager) fame) was already a Captain commanding the Oberth-class science vessel [USS Bonestell](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Bonestell), her first command - a fact which excluded her as [Jean-Luc Picard's](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jean-Luc_Picard) top choice to replace [Commander Riker](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/William_T._Riker) should he accept command of the [USS Aries](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Aries) earlier that year.

As for special meaning, [Jeri Taylor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jeri_Taylor) has gone on record<sup>1</sup> as saying that the VOY captain was originally going to be named "Elizabeth Janeway" after the [author of the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Janeway), but could not be used for legal reasons and was changed. Several writers worked on TNG's "[Man of the People](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Man_of_the_People_(episode))" (despite not having credits)<sup>2</sup>, and Jeri Taylor was writing for TNG at that time, so it's entirely possible that she wrote Act III and simply used the name in both cases.

<sup>1: [Star Trek: Voyager - A Vision of the Future](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Voyager_-_A_Vision_of_the_Future)</sup>
<sup>2: [Captains' Logs: The Unauthorized Complete Trek Voyages](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Captains%27_Logs:_The_Unauthorized_Complete_Trek_Voyages)</sup>

---

### Now Let's Speculate!

That said, there ARE some striking similarities between the two, so let's have fun speculating about an in-universe relationship:

- Both serve in Starfleet
- Both share the same build, face shape, and hair color
- Both are Caucasian and have accents from the Midwestern US
- Both share an affinity for the Sciences Division

All of this is likely just a coincidence, but Captain Janeway does have a sister named Phoebe, who is four years younger. If we do some number-crunching, we know that Janeway left high school around 19 years before 2373 (when she gave up tennis). That means she was roughly 37 when Voyager made it back to the Alpha Quadrant. This would have put her about 27 in 2369, with her sister then being 23. Well, hey - what do you know? Ensign Janeway appears to be in her early-to-mid 20's in 2369. Could Ensign Janeway be Phoebe?

[image]

**Naaaaaaaah.**

***Note:*** Out-of-universe, there's no way the physical similarities are anything but a coincidence. The TNG episode "Man of the People" aired at least two years before Kate Mulgrew had even auditioned for the role of Kathryn Janeway.

Comment: The ensign could have been Stanley Janeway.

Comment: @Omegacron:   I didn't realize that speaking role was Janeway.   How do we know that?

Comment: @ThePopMachine credits on the TNG episode. Actress Lucy Boryer played "Ensign Janeway" and that is Lucy Boryer.

Comment: @Omegacron:   No answer to the main aspect of the question:  Does the name 'Janeway' have some special meaning for some member of the writing or production staff?

Comment: Out of universe, [Geneviève Bujold](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Genevi%C3%A8ve_Bujold) was originally cast to play Janeway. Kate Mulgrew was cast at the last minute when they decided that Bujold wouldn't work out.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - updated. It seems Jeri Taylor was a fan of English author Elizabeth Janeway. She was writing for TNG in 1992, but I can't find whether or not she named the Ensign Janeway character. The credited writer for "Man of the People" said that each writer wrote an Act. If Taylor wrote Act 3, or otherwise named the character, she just liked the name for that reason.

Comment: @Omegacron : Nice work! :-)

Comment: @Omegacron:  Can you give citation for 'on the record..' and 'several writers worked'

Comment: @ThePopMachine: done!

Comment: This raises the question:  What the heck happened to [Lucy Boryer](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0097633/)?    It appears she has a regular role on Doogie Howser and then dropped off the face of the planet for 18 years, only to resurface and then go stealth again.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: no idea, she popped up in 2012 then poof. Hollywood is like a big shredder that chews people up and spits 'em out.

Comment: http://thefw.com/doogie-howser-m-d-then-and-now/

Comment: Legal reasons? How can it be illegal to name someone some specific choice?

Comment: @JDługosz - not sure how it works in other countries, but in the US you can't legally name a fictional character after a real person unless you have permission from the person or (in the case of dead people) their estate. Most Hollywood movies will have a disclaimer somewhere in the credits that says any similarity to real people is not intended. That's basically in there so that some random person with that name can't turn around and sue the studio/script writer/director/etc.

Comment: So the author of *Johnny Tremain* had to track down the estates of all the founding fathers and other figures, before publishing?  I find it hard to beleive that everyone said yes to the author of *Hamilton*.

Comment: @JDługosz - I'm just putting down what Jeri Taylor herself said. You'll have to contact her for details.

Comment: I have some issues with the years and ages mentioned in this answer. If Janeway left high school around 2354 -- as claimed in the answer -- that'd put her date of birth at around 2336, making her approximately 42 years old, rather than 37, when the USS Voyager returned to the Alpha Quadrant in 2378. Also, if she was 37 in 2378 -- as claimed in the answer -- that'd make her 28 in 2369, rather than 27. Also, while her precise age when taking command of Voyager in 2371 is unconfirmed within the canon, there's no way I buy that she was as young as 29.

Comment: @LogicDictates - actually, the birthyear shown on-screen in "The Killing Game" is 2344, which puts her even younger (27) when she assumed command of Voyager. Unfortunately, there's no consistency between the books and the show, or even episodes within the show.

Comment: @Omegacron - When you have conflicting data points, I'm inclined to go with the ones that make the most sense. And it makes more sense to believe that Janeway was in her early 40s in Caretaker, as the script indicated, than her late 20s.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible that the characters are the same in person the timeline, however using the same actress in TNG and voyager would require royalties being paid to that episodes writers in much the same way as lacarno/paris. The only difference being they used the same actor for lacarno and paris so they had to change the name to make the character sufficiantly different to avoid royalties.

Comment: Surely Ensign Janeway doesn't appear, so there is no actress.

Comment: @Chenmunka: What do you mean by that?